# Login authentication in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am creating a app in ionic2. I am facing an issue that on successful login in the app, if I refresh the page it again forces me to login screen but it should not as I have been logged in.

I have used Ionic 2 with menus as a kick start.

Steps I did:

1. Set root page as Loginpage insteed of Page1 which one was default in app.component.ts file.

   `rootPage: any = Loginpage;`
2. On clicking submit redirect to newly created `homepage.ts` as:

   `this.navCtrl.push(Homepage,{});`
3. In `homepage.ts`, I set my root page as any of one page say page2 as:

   `this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page2);`

   - Now on successful login I am redirected to Page2 correctly but if I reload the page at this time it again pushes me back to login page (but I am already logged in).
   - So the question is that how to overcome this issue?
   - What is the better approach for login authentication in ionic2.

Comment: are you doing this in phone/emulator? and how are you checking if loggedin

Comment: basically i am testing it in chrome browser itself not app installed in phone. I am using login api created with PHP laravell framework and on its success i am redirecting it to homepage.

Comment: Can you please suggest is the way i am using correct or their is another way used in ionic2. I mean is there a module which is used to perform this or we do as i did in a custom way ... ?? this is my main doubt.

Comment: you are basically using ionic serve on browser. It will reload the whole app. You will have to test in emulator/phone for this.

Comment: ok thanks @Suraj i will do the same . Thanks for replying. Can you please tell me if this way is correct or i shall go with a different approach thanks again.

Comment: Actually being new to ionic unable to figure out if the approach is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are basically using ionic serve on browser. It will reload the whole app. You will have to test in emulator/phone for this.

Regarding the approach you have in the question:

After login you should set root as home page instead of push.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(Homepage,{});
```

and push the other pages later.

```
this.navCtrl.push(Page2);
```

to maintain the navigation stack.
Check the [Navcontroller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) here.

Comment: Thanks suraj i will look at it.

Comment: Hi Suraj can you please help me on this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297845/preventing-loging-out-on-pressing-back-button-ionic2  ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- you can store Flag in local-storage, If you get this flag than redirect to Your 
  Homepage or login page
- Write below code in your app.component.ts

---

```
 import { Platform, App } from 'ionic-angular';

 constructor(public platform  : Platform,
             public app       : App )
        {
          platform.ready().then(() => {
               if(localStorage.getItem('appToken'))
                   this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage);
               else
                  this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
          });
       }
```