# Preventing loging out on pressing back button Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

Actually I am creating an App in Ionic2 in which I have set my root page as loginpage in which user adds his credentials and on successfull login is redirect to another pages using setRoot say Page1.

The issue is that on pressing back button from app in mobile app closes and user is forced again to login screen but I want its session to be set.

Can any one suggest whats the issue and how I can overcome this.

I have used ionic2 with menus as a kick start.

Comment: add some code..storage,login

Comment: Why the downvotes ? 
There was a clear definition of the problem, and only some guidance was needed. Can people stop downvoting for no reason ? 
I understand that some posts deserve it when they do posts like "Please provide code for that" without any work to show beforehand, but there it is not the case. For the sake of SO, go see : The dawn of Documentation: a solstice update

Comment: Question - why not just set a new page as a root after successful auth? I am not sure (without your full code is hard to tell) - but it seems like the problem here is improper use of nav stack. The use case you describe is very "standard" and there is a standard way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come accross this problem before, and my solution was to setup a `LoggedIn` state in a service that I would call from my guard to my login component, making the redirection to the main part of the app if I was already loggedIn.

Example :

This methods calls my ASP.NET Controller that would get a Session parameter (set beforehand by the `login` method) to know if the user has been authenticated or not and then sets the corresponding value to my service boolean (`this.isLoggedIn`).

**Auth.service.ts**

```
setupLoggedInState() {
    // HTTP Request to API
    let lControllerAction: string = "/IsConnectedState";
    let lControllerFullURL: string = this.controllerURL + lControllerAction;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    // Empty body (necessary for this specific call)
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body: "" });
    // Call ASP Controller
    return this.http.get(lControllerFullURL, options)
        .map((res: any) => {
            let data = res.json();
            if (data == true) {
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
            }
        }
        ).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here is an example of making it work with my guard. I have as well some specific code to manage whether the user would manually input an URL or not, so you won't need all of that.

**Auth.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // Set IsLoggedIn if user has been authenticated before
    return this.authService.setupLoggedInState()
        .map(loggedIn => {
            // Check result
            if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
                // Managing redirection as well as manual URL input
                if (state.url === '/login') {
                    this.router.navigate(['/master/accueil']);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                // Allow routing to LoginComponent if not logged in
                if (state.url === '/login')
                    return true;
                // Refuse access to specific URL => Redirect to Login
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

I did it this way because I could save the state server-side with a Session variable. You need to find your own way to save this state if you want to realize this behavior.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Alex, just out of curiosity - what would we have to solve the described problem through this approach and not just doing proper pages "stack" management? There should be no "back button" in the app if the main (homepage) would become new root and the login page is destroyed. Trying to understand what I am missing here. The described use case is very basic and I don't get why we are solving it this way.

Comment: I don't really understand your question... This is old and not really a good solution since it was a mix of ASP.NET and Angular2. You just need to find your own solution to state management when coming into your application. You could try making a request at the `ngOnInit()` of your login page to see if your user is already logged in or something like that. You can also store a JWT token in the session storage. There are tons of solutions to this.
Do not hesitate to open a new issue if you need for your specific use case. Some people will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can show popup to confirm logout.

```
import { Platform, IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular';

  constructor(public platform: Platform, private ionicApp: IonicApp){}

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      //back button handle
      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        let ready = true;
        let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
          this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
          this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
          this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

        if (activePortal) { 
          //If any popup is open, dismiss it.
          ready = false;
          activePortal.dismiss();
          activePortal.onDidDismiss(() => { ready = true; });
          return;
        }
        else {
          if (this.nav.canGoBack()) {
            //You can come to parent screen by pressing back button.
            this.nav.pop();
          } else {
            //After coming back to home screen, you can ask confirmation for logout to user.
            this.confirmLogout();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  confirmLogout() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Log out?',
      message: 'Do you want to log out?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('No clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
```